# scala value toInt is not a member of Any

Tags: scala, types, casting

The println in the following code works (with or without **toInt**)

```
println("retweets : ", e.getOrElse("retweets", 0).toInt)

top10Tweets(""+e.get("text").get, e.getOrElse("retweets", 0).toInt)
```

But when I pass it as an argument of a function (as above), it does not work. It says "value toInt is not a member of Any"

When I remove toInt, it says,

```
    type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Any
[error]  required: Int
```

e is a Map, as follows,

```
  def tweetDetails(obj: twitter4j.Status) = {
   Map(
   "id" -> obj.getUser().getId(),
   "screenName" -> obj.getUser().getScreenName(),
   "text" -> obj.getText(),
   "retweets" -> obj.getRetweetCount(),
   "mentions" -> obj.getUserMentionEntities().length)
  }
```

signature of top10Tweets,

```
def top10Tweets(tweets: String, retweet_c: Int, mention_c: Int) = {
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example, especially the type of `e`.

Answer (score 8):

**edit**:

Ok, with the new information I would suggest you to create a case class that holds the data instead of using a `Map`, this way you will preserve type information. I know it is common to use hashes/maps for that in dynamically typed languages, but in statically typed languages as scala data types are the preferred way.

**orig**:

As I neither know what `e` is, nor what signature `top10Tweets` has, I can only assume. But from your code and the error I assume that `e` is a `Map[String, String]` and you are trying to get the string representation of an integer for the key `"retweets"` and convert it to an `Int`. As a default value you pass in an `Int`, so the type inferencer infers type `Any`, because that is the most common super type of `String` and `Int`. However `Any` does not have a `toInt` method and thus you get the error.

```
Map("x" -> "2").getOrElse("x", 4).toInt
<console>:8: error: value toInt is not a member of Any
              Map("x" -> "2").getOrElse("x", 4).toInt
```

Either pass in the default value as `String`, or convert the value of `"retweets"` to an `Int` before, if it exists:

```
e.get("retweets").map(_.toInt).getOrElse(0)
```

Anyway a little more information would help to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, e.get("retweets").map(_.toInt).getOrElse(0) ,  but still I am getting "value toInt is not a member of Any".... Is it because e is Map(String, Any) ? I updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: Hi Drexin, Thanks. Could you please give me an example about how to use "case class" instead of Map ?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, so I suggest you to read a good book about scala to learn the basics. Pragramming in Scala by Martin Odersky (the creator of scala) is freely available online.

Answer (score 2):

Yes because in Map is "string" -> "string" and You did when getOrElse ( else ) string -> int, thats why its Any.

```
Map("x" -> 2).getOrElse("x", 4).toInt
```

works fine or You can:

```
Map("x" -> "2").getOrElse("x", "4").toInt
```

Comment: In the first example the `toInt` is superfluous. The value returned is already an `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem bothers me before you could check below

```
Map("x" -> 2).getOrElse[Int](x, 4)
```